# How i can do two or more line's on tips

Tags: extjs, extjs4

How I can do two or more line's on tips?

I do :

```
var firstLine = "1st Line";
var secondLine = "2nd Line";
var thirdLine = "3rd Line"
var myTips = firstLine +' '+ secondLine +' '+ thidrLine
```

And I get `"1st Line 2nd Line 3rd Line"`

On tips I want get

```
"1st Line
2nd Line
3rd Line"
```

How I can want it?
I try '\n' and '\r\n' and i didn't get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myTips = firstLine +'<br>'+ secondLine +'<br>'+ thidrLine;
```